# Given $\tan x+ \tan 2x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$, find $\tan x\cot 2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I can't solve this problem. I tried to find $\tan x$ directly by solving cubic equations but I failed.

The problem is to find $\tan x\cot 2x$ given that
$$\tan x+ \tan 2x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, \>\>\>\>\>0<x<\pi/4$$

How am I supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: Recalling that $cot(2x)=\frac{1}{tan(2x)}$, is there a way you can manipulate the equation such that you have $\frac{tan(x)}{tan(2x)}=tan(x)cot(2x)$?

Comment: I tried dividing both sides by $tan2x$ to get $tanxcot2x$ on left side, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is there a restriction on the values of $x$? There are infinitely many such $x$, and the value of $\tan(x) \cot(2x)$ for them is different

Comment: edited :( sorry

Comment: It seems that there isn't anything you can do other than solve the resulting cubic equation for $\tan x$. With the given restriction, we get
$$\tan x=\frac{2}{3\sqrt 3}\left(1+\sqrt{31}\cos\left(\frac 13\arccos\left(\frac{8}{31\sqrt{31}}\right)-\frac{2}{3}\pi\right)\right) \approx 0.35178$$
then substitute into $\tan x\cot 2x=\frac 12\left(1-\tan^2 x\right)$

Answer (score 1):

Denote $y = \tan x \cot 2x = \frac{1-\tan^2x}2$ and express $\tan x+ \tan 2x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ as a system of equations in $x,y$

$$\tan x+\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}=\left(1+\frac1y \right)\tan x=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}
$$
Then, eliminate $\tan x$ to get
$$\frac3{y^3} -\frac{13}{y}-6=0$$
which is a depressed cubic equation in $\frac1y$, yielding

$$\tan x \cot 2x=y= \left( \frac{2\sqrt{13}}3 \cos \left( \frac13\cos^{-1} \frac{27}{13\sqrt{13}}\right) \right)^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2 \tan x}{1-\tan ^2 x}+\tan x=^*\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$.
$$\tan x=-1.45424, \tan x=0.35178, \tan x =2.25716$$
$L=\tan x \cot 2x$ can be written$^{**}$ as $\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\tan ^2 x\right)$ thus possible values are $$L_1=-0.557406,L_2=0.438125,L_3=-2.04739$$

---

$$(^*)\quad \tan x=u \to u^3-\frac{2 u^2}{\sqrt{3}}-3 u+\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=0$$
see solutions [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%202%2FSqrt%5B3%5D%20-%203%20u%20-%20%282%20u%5E2%29%2FSqrt%5B3%5D%20%2B%20u%5E3%20%3D%3D%200). (press *Approximate forms* button)
$$(^{**})\quad\tan x \cot 2x=\frac{\sin x\left(\cos ^2 x-\sin ^2 x\right)}{\cos x(2 \sin x \cos x)}=\frac{\cos ^2 x-\sin ^2 x}{2\cos^2 x}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\tan^2 x\right)$$

Comment: looks like OP didn't know how to solve the cubic

Comment: @5201314 Neither do I. That's why I linked WA

Answer (score 0):

If $t:=\tan x$ then $\frac{t(3-t^2)}{1-t^2}=\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ so $t^3-\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}t^2+3t+\tfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}=0$. This has [one real root](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+t%5E3-%282%2Fsqrt%283%29%29t%5E2%2B3t%2B2%2Fsqrt%283%29%3D0), $t=\tfrac{2+33/a-a}{3\sqrt{3}}$ with $a:=\sqrt[3]{154+9\sqrt{443}}$. Now just calculate $\frac{1-t^2}{2}$.